# java need a child object to change data in the parent

Tags: java, swing

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm fairly new to java.

Anyway, I need the child object to update a variable in the parent in order to display progress information.

```
package XXX
{

    class aaa
    {
        //has Main()    
        //instantiates an instance of bbb and runs it.    
        bbb myForm = new bbb();
        myForm.setVisible(true);
    }


    class bbb
    {
        public JTextField jProgressField = new JTextField();
        //builds a form with buttons that also shows jProgressField.
        //when you push the "go" button, it instantiates CCC object and tells it to do stuff
        ccc doStuff = new ccc();
        doStuff.goAndConquer();
    }

    class ccc
    {
        protected goAndConquery()
        { 
        //blah blah blah
        //processes a file
        //needs to update ccc with progress information that will still be there to be read when ccc.goAndConquer ends and goes out of scope
        }
    }
}
```

All one package.

Three classes in three files.

The code works and stuff happens... but... I need to update the form (an instance of bbb) with data from ccc while the processing happens (a progress bar and running log of what has happened). 
How do I send a stream of data back to the "parent" or calling instance / object?

In essence, in ccc, I want to do this ( repeatedly, as it runs through the file being processed)

```
myParentWhoCreatedMeAndCalledMe.jProgressField = myParentWhoCreatedMeAndCalledMe.jProgressField + "next line of status information";
```

Comment: Pls provide us full code. It is not readable.

Comment: I agree with @Piotrowy, sort of -- I want to see your [mcve], not your "full code". If you have a serious problem and need serious help, then post serious **real** code, not sort-of kind-of code. Shoot, your code doesn't even show inheritance, and your question makes it look like you may even be misusing inheritance.

Comment: I may be misusing inheritance. I don't know.

Comment: Amit already successfully answered the question, so I'm not feeling a real need to update the question. It was apparently clear enough for Amit to recognize the problem and respond in a constructive and useful fashion. Off to finish testing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do I send a stream of data back to the "parent" or calling instance / object?**
"parent" is not the right word here, as ccc doesn't extend bbb.

Suppose your class bbb has a field data which you want to update:-

```
class bbb{
 private String data;

 public String getData(){
  return data;
 }

public void setData(String data){
this.data=data;
}
}
```

In your your class bbb, there is a call to a method by ccc instance, which need to update data field of bbb  :-

```
ccc doStuff = new ccc(this);
doStuff.goAndConquer()
```

Your class ccc will look like below:-

```
class ccc{

private bbb b;

public ccc(bbb b){
  this.b=b;
}

//Now while processing your file just do below
// b.setData(dataToBeSet);

}
```

Just pass the instance of bbb to ccc and update it.

Comment: So instead of complaining about the formatting of the question, Amit read it, recognized the problem, and provided an answer. I was able to use Amit's answer to do what I need to do in about 10 minutes of code changes. Bravo to Amit!